# Where are the configurations for CoreDNS stored in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I was digging into CoreDNS recently on a cluster where kubeadm was used to install it. I see that I have a default deployment of 2 replicas, but what if I want more? I know I can scale, but that is an extra step that I'd rather not take. I want it so that all new clusters created have 3 CoreDNS for HA (since I will have 3 Masters). But I cannot find any information on where the manifests are stored which kubeadm uses.

I also want to set pod anti-affinity rules for the pods.

I may also want to configure the CoreDNS configmap.

Where are the configurations stored which kubeadm uses to install and configure CoreDNS?

Answer (score 0):

The configurations for CoreDNS are hard-coded into the manifest.go file. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cmd/kubeadm/app/phases/addons/dns/manifests.go#L59

Therefore, if you wanted customizations, you could fork the kubeadm branch and build your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the configuration of CoreDNS in this way.

```
kubectl describe configmap coredns  -n=kube-system
```

Output:

```
Name:         coredns
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
Corefile:
----
.:53 {
    errors
    health {
       lameduck 5s
    }
    ready
    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
       pods insecure
       fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
       ttl 30
    }
    prometheus :9153
    forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
       max_concurrent 1000
    }
    cache 30
    loop
    reload
    loadbalance
}


BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

### How does this ConfigMap take effect?

1. The CoreDNS is defined in a deployment with 2 replicas.
2. The configmap is mounted to the container as a volume.

Here is the definition of this deployment.

```
kubectl describe deployment coredns -n=kube-system
```

[image]

### Reference

- [Kubernetes Doc: Customizing DNS Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns)